# change span text inside a button tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, button, html

I have html structure like this,

```
<button class="myBtn myBtnCTA signIn" onclick="javascript:;">
                            <span>Close</span>
</button>
```

I want to change the text from "Close" to "Save & Close". I tried this `$(button .myBtn myBtnCTA signIn span).text()` but this doesnt seem to work. Any suggestion??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.` dot to join multiple classes, also give selector in `quotes`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pWfEV/)**

```
$('button.myBtn.myBtnCTA.signIn span').text()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".myBtn.myBtnCTA.signIn span").text("Hello world!");
```

Beware that this selector *may be* inefficient.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
$(".myBtn.myBtnCTA.signIn>span").text("Save & Close");
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1387/)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$(".myBtn.myBtnCTA.signIn span").text("text");
```